# do_compile fails when building an image using the yocto-project "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, yocto

I tried to append a layer from git (https://github.com/sigysmund/meta-lora-net) to my Image and whenever I try to bitbake one of the recipes (the other worked), I get this error message:

```
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_configure: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.23440)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.23440
```

(see last part for full message)

I have already tried to edit the bb file.
I changed the DEPENDS to "lora-gateway pkgconfig" instead of just the name since I read on another thread, that this can produce Issues but it didn't help.
This is the bb file of the recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "LoRa network packet forwarder project"
SECTION = "libs/network"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM =                "file://LICENSE;md5=22af7693d7b76ef0fc76161c4be76c45"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a1f942e0cc7b02d604b11c8cb5f2a029"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "e68fadf6f1d2e5e7b601e504d5efb48b0a8f374c2c29c0476ab2fe9db68d33ae"

#old: DEPENDS += "lora-gateway" 
# since new release of yocto you should add pkg-config
DEPENDS += "lora-gateway pkgconfig"

S = "${WORKDIR}/packet_forwarder-${PV}"

CFLAGS_append = "-I ${includedir}/libloragw -I ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/inc -I ${S}/util_tx_test/inc "

do_configure_prepend() {
export LGW_PATH="${STAGING_LIBDIR}/libloragw"
}

do_compile_prepend() {
    export LGW_PATH="${STAGING_LIBDIR}/libloragw"
}

do_install() {
install -d ${D}${bindir}
install -d ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/conf

install ${B}/lora_pkt_fwd/lora_pkt_fwd ${D}${bindir}
install ${B}/util_*/util_* ${D}${bindir}

install -D -m 0644 ${S}/PROTOCOL.TXT ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/PROTOCOL.TXT
install -D -m 0644 ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/readme.md ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/readme.md
install -D -m 0644 ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/global_conf.json ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/global_conf.json
install -D -m 0644 ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/local_conf.json ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/local_conf.json
install -D -m 0755 ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/update_gwid.sh ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd
install -D -m 0644 ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/cfg/*.json.* ${D}${docdir}/lora-pkt-fwd/conf

rm -f ${D}${bindir}/util_tx_test
rm -f ${D}${bindir}/.debug/util_tx_test
}

PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT_STYLE = "debug-without-src"

PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN} ${PN}-doc"

# Avoid QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"

FILES_${PN}-dbg = " \
    ${bindir}/.debug \
"
FILES_${PN} = " \
    ${bindir}/* \
"
FILES_${PN}-doc = " \
    ${docdir} \
"
```

the full error is:

```
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_configure: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.23440)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.23440

Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| NOTE: make clean
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| make clean -e -C lora_pkt_fwd
| make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/packet_forwarder-4.0.1/lora_pkt_fwd'
| Makefile:17: /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/sysroots/mtcdt/usr/lib/libloragw/library.cfg: No such file or directory
| make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/sysroots/mtcdt/usr/lib/libloragw/library.cfg'.  Stop.
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/packet_forwarder-4.0.1/lora_pkt_fwd'
| make: *** [clean] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.23440)
ERROR: Task (/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/layers/meta-custom/recipes-wireless/lora-pkt-fwd/lora-pkt-fwd_4.0.1.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1590 tasks of which 1580 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/layers/meta-custom/recipes-wireless/lora-pkt-fwd/lora-pkt-fwd_4.0.1.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I know that is has got something to do with the libloragw/library.cfg file but since that is imported and I don't know enough about these scripts, I can't find the error.

Any hint is really appreciated!

P.s I didn't include the logfiles since everything in there is already in the Log data follows part of the error. If you need it I can upload it.

Edit:
Thank  you jku, appending CLEANBROKEN = "1" fixed this error.
Sadly I am getting  a new one:

```
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: lora-pkt-fwd-4.0.1-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.24486)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.24486
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| make all -e -C lora_pkt_fwd
| make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/packet_forwarder-4.0.1/lora_pkt_fwd'
| Makefile:17: /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/sysroots/mtcdt/usr/lib/libloragw/library.cfg: No such file or directory
| make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/sysroots/mtcdt/usr/lib/libloragw/library.cfg'.  Stop.
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/packet_forwarder-4.0.1/lora_pkt_fwd'
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/kilian/mlinux-4.x/build/tmp/work/arm926ejste-mlinux-linux-gnueabi/lora-pkt-fwd/4.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.24486)
```

So there is still a problem with the libloragw/library.cfg file

I did check and there is such a file in the recipe given by the DEPENDS variable so I guess that including that and the corresponding commands don't work

```
CFLAGS_append = "-I ${includedir}/libloragw -I ${S}/lora_pkt_fwd/inc -I ${S}/util_tx_test/inc "

do_configure_prepend() {
export LGW_PATH="${STAGING_LIBDIR}/libloragw"
}

do_compile_prepend() {
    export LGW_PATH="${STAGING_LIBDIR}/libloragw"
}
```

But I still don't know what to edit so any help is precious.

Answer (score 1):

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure 
| NOTE: make clean
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| make clean -e -C lora_pkt_fwd
```

Yocto/OpenEmbedded tries to run "make clean" during configure to ensure a reproducible build but this particular project fails to do so cleanly. You can either fix the project (patching the Makefile) or add

```
CLEANBROKEN = "1"
```

in the recipe: this way OpenEmbedded won't run make clean on configure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to read this. I did add the Cleanbroken line to the bb file but now i get a different error. Since it is too long for a comment, I will edit the question.